# How can I develop placeholder or marker in Excel with EPPlus?

Tags: excel, templates, .net-core, epplus, markers

I want to define placeholders (or markers) in an Excel template file.
Example:
Define #Customer.Name or {Customer.Name} in Excel and replace it with the value from the DB in C# .Net core:

> [image: Blockquote]

Of course, the placeholders should be more complex and able to map the nested DTO´s.
Is it possible to develop placeholders with EPPLUS? Is there a concrete example of this?